# modify gstreamer plugin for ios

Tags: ios, plugins, cross-compiling, gstreamer

I have modified the GStreamer rtpjitterbuffer plugin and now I want to cross compile it for iOS. The cerbero build system can cross compile the sdk but I did not understood how can I compile a specific package (get-plugins-good) with my own changes in the source code. Can anyone provide some info about how can this be done?
Thanks